# A file calls the function of the B file to get the file name of the A file

Tags: python

Such as the title. What should I do with python3?

> test1.py

```
import os
def get_file_name():
    return os.path.basename(__file__)
```

> test2.py

```
from test1 import get_file_name
file_name = get_file_name()
print(file_name)
```

now, I want to get the file name of test2

Comment: did you try printing `__file__` from inside test2.py?

Comment: Why can't you simply do ``os.path.basename(__file__) ``?

Answer (score 0):

Change `test1.py` to:

```
import os, inspect
def get_file_name():
    return os.path.basename(inspect.stack()[1].filename)
```